Talend upload file to SharePoint (graphAPI) document libraries , file types are unknown
I have project, using Talend, where an oracle blob is decoded into a file.
I need to 'PUT' the file into a SharePoint document library. i have all the drive id's etc tested in postman as well as putting the file successfully. Translating that into Talend has been unsuccessful.  If I am using tRest, how would I set up the filepath/file (where the decoded files are saved) in a tRest body?
Thanks.
i tried searching for a similar scenario. could not find what to put in the body.
